# enqueueReadBuffer or enqueueMapBuffer throw JNI on Android

Tags: android, java-native-interface, opencl

I am tryng to use enqueueMapBuffer rather than enqueueReadBuffer to send openCL buffer data to android java using JNI.

If i use enqueueMapBuffer everything work well. But if i use enqueueMapBuffer i got nothing. Compilation work well. So i supose that OpenCL do not share the memory with java but only
inside the C code declaration.

Inside the JNI C code i can use enqueueMapBuffer to get the memoty adress of the buffer an use it to get the data and use it.

I anderstand that enqueueReadBuffer will copy the data at the adress of the output pointer. But giving the Output openCL buffer pointer back to Java does not allow java to get acces to the data.

So May be someone could explain my why it cannot be done.

I resume the processing :

1. I lock the output (Java Bitmap) to (uint32_t*) and use it to send back the buffer data to Java.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry,

I complitly forgeted that java do not use the pointer.